# Error while finding module specification for 'pip' (AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__')

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8

Long story short, I did a pip upgrade and a command that told it to install a bunch of dependencies in one file, and now when i try to do anything with pip, it is throwing me

For example, running

```
py -m pip -V
```

throws

```
Error while finding module specification for 'pip' (AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__')
```

Along with anything else that involves my trying to call my python 3.8 pip.

Running

```
py -m ensurepip
```

Tells me that pip is infact installed.

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (60.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (21.3.1)
```

Which covers the pip not installed, and module not installed case that similar questions appear to be solved by. So, does anyone have any idea what is going on and how to get pip to start working again as a module?

Comment: Same problem here with Python 3.10! I ran a script that upgrades pip and setuptools and installs some dependencies from a requirements.txt file into a virtual environment. It worked fine before, but today I encountered the error you reported. What confuses me is that the latest pip release is out for quite some time and has worked before. But I noticed that a new version of setuptools was released some hours ago. Maybe there is a connection to this issue...?

Comment: Without knowing more about your environment it's hard to say, but I expect that even if you spend a lot of time answering questions about your environment, the quickest solution here is to recreate your virtual environment, or if this is happening in your global environment reinstalling this version of Python and then reinstalling your requirements.

Comment: The strange thing is that it occurs in a new virtual environment, as well as in the global environment since the error occurred for the first time. In the global environment (installed from the Arch Linux repositories) the versions of pip and setuptools are much older than in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This was a bug with setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3002). Version 60.3.1 [has now been released](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3002#issuecomment-1006710343) to fix it.

---

Previously, version 60.3.0 [was yanked](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3002#issuecomment-1006266993) from PyPI, which I believe resolves the issue once you run another upgrade. (I wasn't hit by it myself.) If not, GitHub user [ferrants](https://github.com/ferrants) suggested [this workaround](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3002#issuecomment-1006265997):

> ```
> python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools==60.2.0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, and I need use `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools==60.2.0`

Comment: Isn't this the same as the workaround in my answer? I guess there could be situations where `pip3` and `python3 -m pip` are different, but that'd be a weird setup. In that case you could also specify the right Python interpreter, like `~/bin/python3 -m pip`.